# Do "namespaced" include paths in CMake and C++ projects have benefits when integrating projects together?

Tags: c++, cmake

While orienting myself to one of the open source C++ project I found a line of code in the root CMakeLists.txt file:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)
```

And then in one of the source files there is this line:

```
#include "someFolder/someFile.h"
```

`someFolder` is found in `include` folder.

I have seen a different approach in another project,
in which the CMakeLists.txt has something like this:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/someFolder)
```

then in the source file:

```
#include "someFile.h"
```

The first approach typically "namespaces" the include path by the name of the project the header belongs to. Are there common benefits to this when integrating multiple projects together? If so, what are those common benefits?

Comment: first one is more 'linux-like' which I find nicer. `someFolder` is kind of encapsulation for .h files. It's harder to fall into .h name conflicts.

Comment: Not really a cmake question, as it could be generalized to any build tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer subdirectories for include files.

The main reason for this is to avoid file name conflicts. If dependency `A` has a file called `someFile.h`, and dependency `B` also has a file called `someFile.h`, you got a problem, because the compiler doesn't know which one to include.

So for the same reason you should use namespaces, you should also use subdirectories for include files when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is very opinion based, in my opinion...

I prefer the former approach, especially for larger libraries. It exhibits the logical structure of the library as intended for by the authors.

Comment: Not really opinion-based, but toolchain-based. If project's tree contains headers with duplicate names, one of which globally available by default path, certain compilers, gcc included would choose one based on location of file it was included from. First approach excludes that for gcc, but got issues, with e.g. MS one.